# Using a variable to select a drop down option [Selenium]

Tags: python, selenium

This is a simple question, but I don't exactly know how to do it

```
expmonth = 05
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='credit_card_month']/option[@value=expmonth]").click()
```

How would I be able to have the drop down list select the value using the variable?

Comment: this has nothing to do with selenium, it's a basic programming skill to contact string and variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
expmonth = 05
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='credit_card_month']/option[@value=" + expmonth + "]").click()
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems like a dumb question now, but I am still learning.

Answer (score 0):

From [Selenium Docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html), a simple solution.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

expmonth = 05
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='credit_card_month']")
select.select_by_value(expmonth)
```